# How to detect .NET Framework installation on a machine using VB6

Tags: vb6

Using Visual Basic 6, what is the best way to detect if the .NET Framework is installed on a client machine, and what versions of .NET are installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question with the following code based.

```
 Dim strFrameworkDir As String

    strFrameworkDir = Environ$("systemroot") & "\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"

    If Dir$(strFrameworkDir, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then

        MsgBox ".NET Framework 3.5 Must be Installed on this machine!"         
        End

    End If
```

Answer (score 5):

[Check the subfolders in the `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework` folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785/en-us).

Answer (score 2):

you may take this information from windows system registry.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\